# iOS direct sound recording to .m4a file (audio/mpeg-4) using TPAACAudioConverter

Tags: ios, audio, recording, aac, mpeg-4

I work on iOS app with recording feature. I have big problem with **straight AAC mpeg4-audio recording in .m4a file**.

My working solution is recording in .caf and then converting this file in required .m4a format, but is it slow and not acceptable.

I found the Michael Tyson's wrapper [**TPAACAudioConverter**](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter), which is maybe the right solution, but my problem is, that i don't know how to correct initialize and use this wrapper for direct AAC recording in .m4a file (without the supplementary post-conversion after recording).

If anyone have the working example on Github or can me help with it, please let me know.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPAACAudioConverter's not well suited for live recording, just because of the way it's structured, pulling audio from a delegate instead of offering the ability to send audio to it directly.

I recommend using the ExtAudioFile services directly, as it already does the work for you.

If you really have to use TPAACAudioConverter, you'll need to use a ring buffer (like TPCircularBuffer) to store audio until TPAACAudioConverter retrieves it via the delegate method. It's messy though; use ExtAudioFile.

For the record, The Amazing Audio Engine contains a very simple mechanism for recording straight to AAC, or any other supported format. It'll be out soon.

Comment: Thank you Michael, so I'll wait for the referred audio framework. It will be free of charge or paid? Thank you for additional informations.

Comment: No problem - it'll be free and open source

Comment: @MichaelTyson may i ask how to reinitialise an audio session ?
i followed your sample code and got it work for the first time but i got a alert telling me could't initialise audio session!. did i missed out some steps ?

Comment: Actually, you can't reinit an audio session, @Desmond; once it's initialised, that's it. You can change category and other settings, though.